# XMLHttpRequest fail on AWS Amplify for requesting HTML

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to use Jquery's ajax method to request a document to load into my page on AWS amplify. I get a 403 error from Amplify, even though the script and requested document are hosted on the same site.

I tried this from the Chrome Developer console within my web page:

```
$.ajax({type:"GET", url : "/_status_normal.inc"}).done(r=>console.log(r));
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>K1EQ6385K38BZRWK</RequestId>
<HostId>rebHmO5sssss/pqNIomerEo/mVbCVliqu6sycTOXfc=</HostId>
</Error>
```

How do I make a simple XMLHTTPRequest using jQuery with AWS Amplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '/' is wrong when requesting these local resources.  The proper request is:

```
$.ajax({type:"GET", url : "_status_normal.inc"}).done(r=>console.log(r));
```

API Gateway is the AWS method of setting up HTTP GET/POST requests and disabling CORS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html